# using automapper to map data returned from a data reader to generic types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have the following method in my program that fetches data from different table in my database. What i need to do is map the data in different collection depending of the input query. Each query will target data from a different table. The details of table are irrelevant and the comment i need is mostly related how to configure autompapper to acheive this.

My initial code is described below:

```
   private async Task<List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> LoadData(SqlConnection conn)
{
    List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
    string sql = QueryForTheData;
    List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> result = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
    var reader = await new SqlCommand(sql, conn).ExecuteReaderAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        columnNames.Add(reader.GetName(i));
    }

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> FoundRecords = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            FoundRecords.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key: columnName, value: reader[columnName].ToString()));
        }
        result.Add(FoundRecords;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My solution to this using Automapper is as follow:

```
 private async Task<List<TResult>> LoadData<TResult>(SqlConnection conn)
{
    List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
    string sql = QueryForDuplicatesChecking;
    List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> result = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
    var reader = await new SqlCommand(sql, conn).ExecuteReaderAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        columnNames.Add(reader.GetName(i));
    }

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> FoundRecords = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            FoundRecords.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key: columnName, value: reader[columnName].ToString()));
        }
        result.Add(FoundRecords);
    }
    return Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>><,>), typeof(List<TResult><,>));

}
```

I'm not successful at getting this to run.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data

Comment: Thanks you for the link. I haven't seen anything with generic type mapping.

Comment: Why not simply use a DataTable, that's generic, right?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, that is indeed an excellent suggestion. My reason for the custum type was to avoid the extract work of reading from the dataTable in a non type safe way.